# How do I calculate the Relative Humidity from number density and pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, humidity

From some measurements I have determined and calculated the temperature and number density of water molecules in (m^-3) at a pressure of X Pa. How do I get the RH value out of those variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you determined the saturation density from steam tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing the number density by avagadro's number gives you the number of moles per unit volume of water $\rho_w$.  The partial pressure of water vapor is then $$P_{water}=RT\rho_{w}$$If, at temperature T, the equilibrium vapor pressure of water vapor is $P^*(T)$, the relative humidity is $$RH=\frac{RT\rho_W}{P^*}\times 100\ percent$$

Comment: I am not measuring at regular atmospheric pressure though, so how do I compensate for that? I am at a pressure of around 50 Pascals now, so can I just adjust by a factor of 101325/50?

Comment: This is valid at any pressure as long as the ideal gas law applies.

Comment: By adjusting to the experimental pressure, I got a result of around 50% which falls within the expected values, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It appears to (non-expert) me that in the world our air is a very complex thing. It contains not only gases and water but a lot of biological materials such as bacteria, spores, dust... There are electrical phenomena such as ionisation to consider too. The outcome of all this is that humidity needs to be measured, rather than calculated, and the amount of water in a cubic volume of air is not a simple function of relative humidity and temperature.

Comment: I am quite certain that nothing has survived the plasma that was active beforehand but thanks for your input. I am here asking for the physical descriptions and equations that I need to describe this quantity. If I were to ask for a philosophical approach, I'd go to phylisophy.stackexchange.com.